# Когда появилось сокращение имен?

Tags: имена-собственные

И снова об именах.
Тут уже был вопрос по поводу историчности сокращения имен. Но меня интересуют конкретно русские имена. Всегда ли существовали "домашние" сокращения имен вроде Ваня, Маша, Петя и т.д.? И, если нет, то когда они появились?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если говорить о Ване, Маше, Пете и других заимствованных именах, то сокращения имён должны были возникнуть почти сразу, после того как они стали употребляться в быту. Иначе, несвойственные русскому языку сочетания звуков, делали бы общение с использованием имени обременительным. Хотя понятно, что доподлинно установить, когда  произошло данное явление, довольно-таки проблематично.

Если говорить, о дохристианских именах, то в те времена, я сомневаюсь, что была необходимость в сокращении имён, для удобства произношения, так как использовались только удобные звукосочетания. К тому же у человека вполне могло быть и несколько имён-прозвищ, что, вообще, делает сокращение не очень осмысленным.  Среди дохристианских имён выделяют следующие группы:

- Числовые имена. Среди них представлен весь числовой ряд от 1 до 10: Перва и Первой, Вторак, Третьяк, Четвертак, Пятой и Пятак, Шестак, Семой и Семак, Осьмой и Осьмак, Девятко, Десятой. Они отражают порядок рождения детей в семье.
- Имена, данные по внешним признакам, цвету волос и кожи. Весьма распространёнными были имена Черныш, Черняй, Чернява, Бел, Беляй, Беляк, Белуха. Также встречались имена, связанные с особенностями телосложения: Мал, Малюта, Малой, Долгой, Сухой, Толстой, Голова, Головач, Лобан, Беспалой.
- Имена, связанные с чертами характера, привычками и поведением. Встречались имена Забава, Истома, Крик, Скряба, Молчан, Неулыба, Булгак (беспокойный), Смеяна и Несмеяна.
- Имена, отражавшие желанность или нежеланность появления ребёнка в семье, отношение родителей к ребёнку: Богдан и Богдана, Бажен (желанный), Голуба, Любава, Ждан и Неждан, Хотен, Чаян и Нечай.
- Имена, связанные со временем года, в которое родился ребёнок: Вешняк, Зима, Мороз.
- Имена, связанные с животным и растительным миром: Бык, Волк, Щука, Кот, Кошка, Жеребец, Корова, Щавей (от щавель), Трава, Пырей. Предполагают, что такие имена могут отражать пережитки тотемных верований предков славян.
- Имена, связанные с поверьями, что «плохие» слова в состоянии отвращать злых духов, болезни, смерть: Горяин, Немил, Некрас, Нелюба, Неустрой, Злоба, Тугарин (от туга — печаль).
- Имена, связанные с соседними народностями: Чудин (от названия финно-угорского племени чудь), Карел, Татарин, Козарин (от названия хазар), Онтоман (от названия турок — оттоманы). История возникновения этой группы имён неясна: возможно, это были охранные имена (данные, чтобы не ссориться с соседями) или пожелательные (чтобы ребёнок был в чём-то похож на того, в честь кого давалось имя); возможно, эти имена связаны со смешанными браками.
- Имена князей  Владимир, Ярослав, Изяслав, Ярополк, Остромир, Святослав, Святополк, Вячеслав, Всеволод и др. Число таких имён невелико, и они имели ограниченное употребление, как правило, только в среде людей благородных сословий; а у каждой ветви Рюриковичей был свой набор подобных имён.

Answer (score 2):

См. http://www.ruslichimya.ru/polnoe-lichnoe-imya-i-ego-proizvodnye/polnoe-imya-i-ego-kratkaya-forma.ini